# How to utilize table partition in oracle database in effective manner?

Tags: sql, oracle, database-partitioning

I have created a partitioned table as

```
CREATE TABLE orders_range(order_id NUMBER 
                         ,client_id NUMBER 
                         ,order_date DATE) 
  PARTITION BY RANGE(order_date) 
    (PARTITION orders2011 VALUES LESS THAN (to_date('1/1/2012','dd/mm/yyyy')) 
    ,PARTITION orders2012 VALUES LESS THAN (to_date('1/1/2013','dd/mm/yyyy')) 
    ,PARTITION orders2013 VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE));
```

when I am selecting the records using

```
SELECT * FROM ORDERS_RANGE partition(orders2011);
```

in explain plan the cpu cost is 75
but when i go for normal query using where clause the cpu cost is only 6 then what is the advantage of table partitioning when it comes to performance?
Can anyone explain me in detail?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to specify which RDBMS are you using.

Comment: What WHERE clause do you use ? Do you have any indexes on the table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you generally can't directly compare the `cost` of two different plans running against two different objects.  It is entirely possible that one plan with a cost of 10,000 will run much more quickly than a different plan with a cost of 10.  You can compare the `cost` of two different plans for a single SQL statement within a single 10053 trace (so long as you remember that these are estimates and if the optimizer estimates incorrectly, many `cost` values are incorrect and the optimizer is likely to pick a less efficient plan).  It may make sense to compare the `cost` between two different queries if you are trying to work out the algorithm the optimizer is using for a particular step but that's pretty unusual.

Second, in your example, you're not inserting any data.  Generally, if you're going to partition a table, you're doing so because you have multiple GB of data in that table.  If you compare something like

```
SELECT *
  FROM unpartitioned_table_with_1_billion_rows
```

vs

```
SELECT *
  FROM partitioned_table_with_1_billion_rows
 WHERE partition_key = date '2014-04-01' -- Restricts the data to only 10 million rows
```

the partitioned approach will, obviously, be more efficient not least of all because you're only reading the 10 million rows in the April 1 partition rather than the 1 billion rows in the table.

If the table has no data, it's possible that the query against the partitioned table would be a tiny bit less efficient since you've got to do more things in the course of parsing the query.  But reading 0 rows from a 0 row table is going to take essentially no time either way so the difference in parse time is likely to be irrelevant.

In general, you wouldn't ever use the `ORDERS_RANGE partition(orders2011)` syntax to access data.  In addition to hard-coding the partition name, which means that you'd often be resorting to dynamic SQL to assemble the query, you'd be doing a lot more hard parsing and that you'd be putting more pressure on the shared pool and that you'd risk making a mistake if someone changed the partitioning on the table.  It makes far more sense to supply a predicate on the partition key and to let Oracle work out how to appropriately prune the partitions.  In other words

```
SELECT *   
  FROM orders_range  
 WHERE order_date < date '2012-01-01'
```

would be a much more sensible query.

Comment: Thank you very much Justin Cave for your sensible answer.